# Consuming UTF-8 BOM

Tags: c++

Given the following code:

```
typedef std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::codecvt_mode::consume_header> MyCodeCvt;
std::wifstream myStream("Test.txt");
std::locale myLocale(myStream.getloc(), new MyCodeCvt());
myStream.imbue(myLocale);
wstring str;
myStream >> str;
myStream.close();
```

This correctly consumes the UTF-8 BOM (EF, BB, BF) in the first 3 bytes of "Test.txt", and "str" is properly set to the data that follows it, but can anyone explain why, if I now change **std::codecvt_mode::consume_header** to **(std::codecvt_mode)0** in the typedef, it still consumes the BOM? Shouldn't the 3 BOM characters now show up in "str" or am I missing something. Note that I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Thanks.

Comment: have you checked the values. have you checked the documentation. have you checked the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I spent considerable time looking into it before posting here, including checking the standard. Either VS2013 is broken, or I'm not correctly understanding something.

Comment: Are you positive that the file contains a BOM?

Comment: @JohnBrown: well, have you tried `std::getline` instead of `>>`? could possibly be that a non-breaking zero width space is treated as whitespace. Note that it's not 3 "characters". It's a single Unicode code point, encoded as 3 bytes with UTF-8, and as 2 bytes with UTF-16.

Comment: @Alf: Yes, tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help. It turned out to be an enviromental problem. I installed VS2013 on another machine and the issue no longer occurs. Surprised by this, I uninstalled and reinstalled it on the problem machine and it no longer occurs there either. Just your typical programmer's SNAFU no doubt (wish I had a nickel for every one). Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

If std::consume_header is not selected when reading a file beginning with byte order mark, the Unicode character U+FEFF (Zero width non-breaking space) will be read as the first character of the string content.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_mode

Comment: I've seen this blurb before but it makes no sense when reading UTF-8 (AFAIK), and it doesn't show up anyway in the example I cited. I would expect it when reading UTF-16 (that's its BOM), and the comment itself only reinforces the idea that when "consume_header" is absent, the BOM should be read. For UTF-8, that means EF, BB, BF.

Comment: ... sorry, my mistake. A BOM is a BOM (UTF-8 or otherwise) but the issue remains (it's not showing up).

Comment: That is what I said.  The BOM gets consumed (so it does not show up) and replaced with U+FEFF.  What bytes do you get in your output buffer after reading the BOM?  Anything other than U+FEFF is a bug and should be reported.

Comment: I would expect that "str[0]" will not contain U+FEFF if "consume_header" is specified (this works), but if "consume_header" is not specified, then "str[0]" will contain U+FEFF. It doesn't however. "str[0]" doesn't contain U+FEFF regardless of "consume_header".